# WPF - How to design a Border that contains a Label on the corner

Tags: wpf

How can I design the following layout in WPF?

[image]

Comment: Almost sounds like you want a path.

Comment: @Tejs: Thomas has given correct answer !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just use a [`GroupBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox.aspx). You can customize the style if the default appearance doesn't suit your needs.

```
<GroupBox Header="Contact information">

    <!-- Content here -->

</GroupBox>
```

Have a look at the [default style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744748.aspx) for pointers on how to customize the appearance.